# How to save an Integer to Parse in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, integer

Im trying to save an `integer` value to [Parse.com](https://parse.com/) but I am getting an error.  I have the object in the Parse class set to a `Number`.

this is my code:

```
  if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() {

        currentUser.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock({ (foundUser: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            // Get and update score

            if foundUser != nil {

                let score = foundUser!["score"] as! Int

                let points = 100 + score

                foundUser!["score"] = points

                foundUser?.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if succeeded {

                        println("score added to user")
                    }
                })

            }

        })

    }
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: What is your error and at which line you are getting it?

Comment: let score = foundUser!["score"] as! Int

Comment: I am getting this as the error:fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Print your score variable and check that if it is possible to convert it to int.

Comment: Printing description of score:
6171707936
Printing description of points:
6176593344

Comment: I get a huge integer that has nothing to do with the score

Comment: you can take it as a `long` value

Comment: Print this:`foundUser!["score"]`

Comment: Do you mean this?Printing description of foundUser:
(PFObject?) foundUser = 0x0000000170192480 {
  ObjectiveC.NSObject = {}
}

Comment: otherwise score is printed as "Printing description of score:
6171707936"

Comment: I don't think the `foundUser!["score"]` is 6171707936. Maybe the 6171707936 is an uninitialized variable value. Because cast a nil to Int which is why you get the error.

Comment: Ok that makes sense because when a user is new the column is nil since they have not done anything yet to earn a score.  I think my problem lies in "if foundUser != nil" since it is only running if there is already a value in the column.  Do you know of a way to execute my code without the foundUser !=nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens because you cast a nil to Int.

I think it works:

```
if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() {

    currentUser.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock({ (foundUser: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        // Get and update score

        if let foundUser = foundUser {
            if let score = foundUser["score"] as? Int {
                foundUser["score"] = 100 + score
            } else {
                foundUser["score"] = 0
            }

            foundUser.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if succeeded {

                    println("score added to user")
                }
            })

        }
    })
}
```

Comment: it makes me change if let foundUser = foundUser, score = foundUser["score"] to if let foundUser = foundUser, score: AnyObject = foundUser["score"] and foundUser["score"] = points.  It also doesn't save to the server for some reason but it still runs so I guess thats a start.

Comment: ugh for some reason the new score just isn't saving the "score added to user" isn't even printing out

Comment: You can print the error like this:`if succeeded {
    println("score added to user")
} else {
    println(error)
}`

Comment: Oh my gosh it finally works!!!!!! Thank you so much for the help!!! You have no idea how long I have been trying to fix this!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should convert your `foundUser!["score"]` to `Int` this way:

```
let score = foundUser?["score"].integerValue
```

**EDIT**

```
if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() {

        currentUser.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock({ (foundUser: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            // Get and update score

            if foundUser != nil {

                if let score = foundUser?["score"].integerValue {
                    let points = 100 + score

                    foundUser!["score"] = points

                    foundUser?.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                        if succeeded {

                            println("score added to user")
                        }
                    })
                }
            }

        })

    }
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Ugh it still doesn't work..Haha I have literally been working on this problem for 5 hours.  I don't understand why it is so complicated.  You would think it would be simple.  Like I said a second ago above I think my problem lies in "if foundUser != nil" since it is only running if there is already a value in the column. Do you know of a way to execute my code without the foundUser !=nil?

Comment: you can use `if let` and unwrap it.

Comment: For some reason it still doesn't save.  Im going to try changing the score column in Parse to a String

Comment: Are you trying to save the user if the user is not in existence?

Comment: @Bannings No I am trying to save the score to the current user

Comment: @TripPhillips I updated my answer. Maybe your logic should be that.